# jqueryMobile and phonegap pageinit and ajax accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

My code:

```
$('#cars').live('pageinit',function() {
    var msg = "";
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://192.168.23.20/php/getcar.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',  
        success: function(data){
        msg += '<div data-role="collapsible-set">';
            $.each(data, function(i,v){
                msg += '<div data-role="collapsible">';
                msg += '<h3>'+v.carName+'</h3>';
                msg += '<p>'+v.cardesc+'</p>';
                msg += '</div>';
            });
        msg += '</div>';
        $(".car").after(msg);
        }
    });         
});
```

The output is displayed as plaintext instead of JQM accordion. Is there any workaround to do JQM accordion on pageinit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are going to create accordion list dynamically or modify dynamically then you need to refresh that particular accordion to get JQM style and effects that you can achive by `$('.selector').collapsibleset('refresh');`

may be this(not tested) works for you.

```
$accordion_div = $('<div data-role="collapsible-set"></div>');
msg = ""
$.each(data, function(i,v){
  msg += '<div data-role="collapsible">';
  msg += '<h3>'+v.carName+'</h3>';
  msg += '<p>'+v.cardesc+'</p>';
  msg += '</div>';
});
$accordion_div.html(msg);
$accordion_div.appendTo(".car").collapsibleset('refresh');
```